# Running Github Actions on OSX results in "Could not find domain for port (Aqua)"

Tags: github-actions

I've followed the directions [here](https://help.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/configuring-the-self-hosted-runner-application-as-a-service), but when I run `./svc.sh run`, I receive the following error:

```
Could not find domain for port (Aqua)
```

I'm SSH-ing into a box to run this command, it seems to work fine when I'm not in a headless session, but I need this to be headless and as a background service.  Anyone else run into this?

Comment: rather then rely fully upon that page it would be good to include the key items here, if that page is moved or altered the question won't be understandable anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this, addressed [here](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/349)

```
sudo cp {/Users/xxx/Library/LaunchAgents,/Library/LaunchDaemons}/your.plist
```

I was able to reboot my machine without logging in and see the runner active

Comment: then mark it as accepted... it would however be much better to post actual content then a link that can break since the answer itself is short.

Answer (score 0):

Solution by @futbolpal not good, because LaunchDaemons doesn't have access to keychain.

Better copy to LaunchAgents
Like:

```
sudo cp {/Users/xxx/Library/LaunchAgents,/Library/LaunchAgents}/your.plist
```

Comment: I am experiencing this issue that you're mentioning here. The runner doesn't have access to my keychains.
However, doesn't this solution you provided kill the runner when the user logs out?

"When the user logs out, it sends a SIGTERM signal to all of the user agents that it started." 

[Ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html)